# New to SQL Server 2008 and setting up specific report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting

I am considerably new to the workings of SQL and I am stumbling my way through setting up reporting for some data.

Here is my code

```
SELECT [course_book no_],
       [customer no_],
       [not a licensed attorney],
       [book type code],
       [total cle credits]
FROM   pcam_data
WHERE  ( [posting date] BETWEEN '07/01/2014' AND '9/30/2014' )
       AND ( [entry no_] NOT IN (SELECT [applies to entry no_]
                                 FROM   pcam_data AS PCam_Data_1
                                 WHERE  ( [entry type] = 1 )) )
GROUP  BY [course_book no_],
          [customer no_],
          [not a licensed attorney],
          [book type code],
          [total cle credits]
```

What I am looking to do is take the course numbers (column 1) and those that are alike (highlighted) part to be summed at the end of the report - Customer numbers do not need to be kept in that summation. Can I ask for some input or some guidance? I can provide an image of the output upon request.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could give us an example of exactly how you want the data to look at the end... even if just roughly.  Much easier than trying to visualise from a description

Comment: Are you hoping to get a SQL query to do this, or are you using something like Reporting Services to show this?

Comment: Thanks Gents for replying, So this report will generate 5 columns. In the first column we will have many courses come up that are the same, but the second makes them distinct as they are done by customer number. the fourth column reports a number

I will try to draw out the example
Course No: c2033-01 Cust No: 001 Deliver method: xxx  Credit 1.0
Course No: c2033-01 Cust No: 002 Deliver method: xxx  Credit 1.0

Although cust1 and cust2 are different the courses they took are the same. I am wanting to build a report that sums up the totals for each course.

Comment: and I have the starting query built (i think lol) @freefaller let me see if I can post an imgur link.

It doesnt have to be neat - just a break down of the course no: with a total at the bottom.

Comment: http://imgur.com/EIwURJg

Comment: @Dissonance79, all you've done is give a link to an image showing exactly what you've already shown. I'd like an example (using pre-formatted text if necessary) showing how the output should look

Comment: I understand, and apologize for that. Ill have that for you asap.